# Send data to a TemplateRef MatDialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to get data sent to a MatDialog that is a `ng-template`?

**Template**

```
<button mat-button (click)="openDialog()">Open</button>

<ng-template #dialogRef>
    {{data?}} <!-- <<< Here is the problem data is undefined -->
</ng-template>
```

**Component**

```
export class SomeComponent {
    @ViewChild("dialogRef") dialogRef: TemplateRef<any>;

    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

    openDialog(): void {
        this.dialog.open(this.dialogRef, { data: "some data" });
    }
}
```

Comment: What data you want to send??

Comment: Any kind of data, some objects, in this case a simple string (`data: "some data"`). It is something possible to achieve when using a separate component for the dialog (with `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data` in the component constructor) but I don't know how to access it with the dialog as a simple ng-template.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It should be available through template variable:

```
<ng-template #dialogRef let-data>
                        ^^^^^^^^
   {{data}}
</ng-template>
```